# PayPal: MALFORMED_REQUEST

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

```html
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
include '../models/panier.php';
include './utils.php';
$ids=require('./paypal.php');

$panier=new Panier(1,'etat',3);
$listArt=Panier::artPanier($panier);
foreach($listArt as $l){
    echo $l->nom;echo ' ';
    echo (madToEur($l->prix));echo ' ';
}
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        $ids['id'],
        $ids['secret']
    )
);
$paypalList=new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();
foreach($listArt as $l){
    $item=new \PayPal\Api\Item();
    $item->setName($l->nom);echo 'item : ';
    echo $item->getName().' ';
    $prix=madToEur($l->prix);
    $item->setPrice($prix);
    echo $item->getPrice().' ';
    $item->setCurrency('EUR');
    $item->setQuantity(1);
    echo $item->getCurrency().' '.$item->getQuantity().' ';
    $paypalList->addItem($item);echo 'added';
}
$details=new \PayPal\Api\Details();
$subtotal=Panier::getTotalPrix($panier);
$subTotalEur=madToEur($subtotal);
echo ' sub '.$subTotalEur;
$details->setSubtotal($subTotalEur);
echo ' '.$details->getSubtotal();
$amount=new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal($subTotalEur);
echo ' total amount '.$amount->getTotal();
$amount->setCurrency('EUR');echo $amount->getCurrency();
$amount->setDetails($details);
echo ' amount details '.$amount->getDetails();
$transaction=new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setItemList($paypalList);echo ' itemlist '.$transaction->getItemList();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);echo ' amount '.$transaction->getAmount();
$transaction->setCustom('demo');echo ' Custom '.$transaction->getCustom();
$transaction->setDescription('desc');echo ' Description '.$transaction->getDescription();
$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$redirectUrls =new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('https://example.com/return');
$redirectUrls->setCancelUrl('https://example.com/cancel');
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
$payment->setPayer((new \PayPal\Api\Payer())->setPaymentMethod('paypal'));
$payment->setTransactions($transaction);


echo $payment->getPayer();
echo $payment->getTransactions();

echo '\n';
echo $payment;









try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
    echo $payment->getApprovalLink();
} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e) {
    var_dump(json_decode($e->getData()));
}

?>
```

```html
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
        "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel"
    },
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": {
        "item_list": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "masqueCh",
                    "price": "1.41",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "quantity": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "masquePeaux",
                         "price": "1.41",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "quantity": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "nomPaque",
                    "price": "1.41",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        "amount": {
            "total": "4.23",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": "4.23"
            }
        },
        "custom": "demo",
        "description": "desc"
    }
}
```

I get the MALFORMED_REQUEST and the data dump. The user is supposed to be taken to PayPal (Sandbox, in this case) for payment processing. I am using the PayPal PHP SDK (REST). I am also using some methods to get the prices of my products, but you can see from the json response that all my methods are working well, but steel can't get the approval Link, i've post my code and also the json that i get from the: echo $payment

Comment: Did you have a look at the [examples](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/)?

Comment: no i didn't, i've seen a tutorial and start coding, but You, you saved my day,my life, and everythings,i've just looked to te examples,made some modifications and it's working well right now thank You so mush .